# Why FadeOut is not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Take a look at this code:

```
<script>
$(function(){
  $("div.note a").live("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    answer = confirm("Delete?");    
    if (!answer) return false;

    $(this).parent().fadeOut('slow', function(){
      $(this).remove();
    });
  });  
});
</script>
```

---

```
<div id="note_list">
  <div class="note">
    Text: 
    <a href="#">X</a>
  </div>  
  <div class="note">
    Text: 
    <a href="#">X</a>
  </div>
  <div class="note">
    Text: 
    <a href="#">X</a>
  </div>
  <div class="note">
    Text: 
    <a href="#">X</a>
  </div>   
</div>
```

Could somone tell me why the fadeout is not working? after the click the div is deleted but i don't see the fedeout effects. Why?

Comment: Works just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/svmg4/

Comment: [Your code works fine.](http://jsfiddle.net/xB3Qy/) Please post code that has been verified to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: This is working for me in the jsfiddle: - http://jsfiddle.net/CNQXV/ The text and the link fade out. Do you have an example online we can see? You probably have some other JavaScript error which is causing a conflict?

Answer (score 3):

It is working, I made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LWLWY/) for you.

If for some reason you still can't see it, try to replace `'slow'` by a number of milliseconds, something big enough like 3000 should do it.

Comment: @Dail: Using `"slow"` shouldn't cause any trouble. It will map to 800ms I believe. EDIT: Actually looks like 600ms https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.6.2/src/effects.js#L542-547

Comment: I found that the fade did not work in Chrome when using 'slow' in the above jsfiddle

Comment: @Deebster: What version of Chrome? Works fine for me.

Comment: Chrome 14.0.835.202 m on Windows 7 Pro

Comment: @Deebster: Strange. I'm on Chrome 15 beta, but I don't recall any issues with v14. Oh well.

Comment: In fact, on this machine setting the fade to 1000 msec or lower results in no fade, whereas higher values result in no animation until a second in whereupon it's jumped to the opacity it should be and smoothly faded the rest of the way out.

Answer (score 0):

you could also try `.fadeTo(3000,0,function(){$(this).remove();})`